# Selenium logic journey - if passes first scenario move to the next url - Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm creating a crawler which will go through a large amount of URLs and will go through a number of scenarios. If one of the scenarios pass I want to write something and check the next url through the scenarios again until one passes.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

    urls = ['https://www.google.com/', 'https://stackoverflow.com/']

    for url in urls:
        driver.get(url)
        image_name = url.split(".")[1] + ".png"
        driver.save_screenshot(image_name)
        performance_data = driver.execute_script('return window.performance.getEntries();')
        for single_data in performance_data:
            if "nav" in single_data["name"]:
                file.write(url + "adserv_1")
                break
#over here the loop should break and look for the new url rather than continuing the below?    

        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,1000);")
        sleep(2)
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,5000);")
        sleep(2)
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,10000);")
        sleep(2)
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        performance_data = driver.execute_script('return window.performance.getEntries();')
        for single_data in performance_data:
            if "nav" in single_data['name']:
                results.write(url + "3")
```

Shouldn't the code go to the next url in the array if the first scenario passes?

Comment: It's an easy fix: set a boolean variable before first break, and then outside the inner loop check for this variable, if true then break again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ‘break’ only exits the ‘for single data’ loop, not the ‘for url’ loop.